# Dynamically Setting DropDown values not refreshing in UI

Tags: acumatica

In Sales Order Entry I have a custom drop down on the line level and a custom drop down on the header.  I want the list of values in the line level drop down to change depending on the value in the Header drop down level.  I added a routine for SOOrder_RowSelected that has a switch depending on the value of the header value to set the list of values in the line level dropdown with PXStringListAttribute.SetList.  This works the first time you load SO Entry, but when you move between records with different values selected for the header dropdown, the list of options in the line level dropdown will not update unless your refresh the page.  Is it possible to refresh the control programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set MatrixMode to the dropdown field with not constant values.
Like that:

```
    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrigTranType" Type="DropDownList" Width="80px" MatrixMode="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set the searchquey for your PXselector with condition Current?

Note: You should set the auto refresh of the selector to true

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm using a drop down so I can set MultiSelect = true and my users can select multiple entries.  Otherwise PXSelector would be a good choice.

Comment: Oh yea. Okay. Happy that u got a rite answer. :)